# Error generated when trying to cite an author's multiple papers at the same time

Tags: natbib, apa-style, apacite

Dears,

I am writing this question post for asking how to solve the error when I try to cite an author's different papers at the same time. I have installed  `\usepackage{apacite}` and `\usepackage{natbib}`, and use the APA citation style: `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.

However, when I try to cite the authors' multiple papers (`\citep{Abdellaoui2007, Abdellaoui2008)` or `\cite{Abdellaoui2007, Abdellaoui2008}`), the year information goes wrong: (Abdellaoui et al., 2007,0) or Abdellaoui et al (2007,0). If it works as expected, the correct one should be (Abdellaoui et al., 2007,2008) or Abdellaoui et al (2007,2008). I am sure the year information is correct in bib file.

Also, I have tried references of other authors, but the problem is same: When enter `\cite{Payne1980,Payne1981}`, it shows Payne et al. (1980,9), which should be Payne et al. (1980,1981).

I hope I express the question clearly, and thanks for your attention in advance.

Best,
Jilong

Comment: @AlanMunn - You're absolutely right. I had become confused with another 'feature' of the `apalike` bibliography style, *viz.*, its habit of reading in just the first 4 characters in the `year` field. This setting makes it impractical to write things like `year = "2017--19"`. I've deleted my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not concerned about conforming to the actual APA guidelines, but just require a generic author/year citation system, the `apalike` + `natbib` combination will do what you need.

The `apacite` package is *not* a generic author/year style, but instead implements fairly faithfully the APA 6 style.  If you need that style in all its detail, and you also want to use `natbib` then you must use `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}\bibliographystyle{apacite}`.  You can *only* use the `apacite` bibliography style with the `apacite` package, and you can't use any other bibliography style if you load the `apacite` package.  Note that proper APA style requires author disambiguation, so if two papers have the same first authors but differ by one author they should not be merged into a single *et al.*.

The `apalike` style doesn't do author disambiguation, which seems to be what you want, so you can achieve this citation style using `natbib` + `apalike`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Smith2019,
    author={Smith, A. and  Jones, B. and Brown, C.},
    title={A great paper on ducks},
    journal={Journal of Quackery},
    volume={3},
    number={1},
    pages={1--10},
    year={2019}}

@article{Smith2020a,
    author={Smith, A. and  Jones, B. and Green, D.},
    title={Another great paper on ducks},
    journal={Journal of Quackery},
    volume={3},
    number={2},
    pages={2--20},
    year={2020}}
@article{Smith2020b,
    author={Smith, A. and  Jones, B. and Yellow, D.},
    title={An even greater paper on ducks},
    journal={Journal of Quackery},
    volume={3},
    number={4},
    pages={6--19},
    year={2020}}


\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{Smith2019,Smith2020a,Smith2020b}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you, Alan. Your detailed answer has clearly resolved my problems. Really appreciate your contribution to this community. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dears,

I find what is the reason for this problem: I install `\usepackage{apacite}` and `\usepackage{natbib}` simultaneously. When I remove `\usepackage{apacite}`, it works well. But When I remove `\usepackage{natbib}`, it does not solve the problem.

I hope this can help others. Of course, if someone knows the deep reason for the conflict between these two packages, an explanation will be very welcome.

Best

Comment: This is not the correct solution. You can use `natbib` and `apacite` together, but you need to load `apacite` with the `[natbibapa]` option. And you *must* use the `apacite` bibliography style, not `apalike`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I adjust my codes as you suggested, the outcome of `\cite(Abdellaoui2007, Abdellaoui2008)` turns out to be  (Abdellaoui,Bleichrodt, & L’Haridon, 2008; Abdellaoui, Bleichrodt, & Paraschiv, 2007), even further from what I want.

Comment: What you want isn't proper APA style. (And it's misleading since the third author of each is not the same, the two citations shouldn't be merged.) For more generic APA styles you might want to consider shifting to `biblatex` and use `ext-authoryear` with appropriate options to implement this style.

Comment: See [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/263800)  and [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/25702) for more discussion of the differences.